# How can I use querid data to exectute another query in mongodb single aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Think I have 2 collection:

1. Man: the documents are-

   ```
   [
     { _id: 1,
       name: 'Jack',
       children: ['Joy','Joe','James']
     },
     { _id: 2,
       name: 'Molly',
       children: ['Milly','Mou']
     }

   ]
   ```
2. Age

   ```
   [{_id:1, name: "Joy", age:10},
    {_id:2, name: "Joe", age:12},
    {_id:3, name: "James", age:14},
    {_id:4, name: "Milly", age:9},
    {_id:5, name: "Mou", age: 6}
   ]
   ```

I am wanting to create a single aggregate,
where in 1st phase I will find  Jack's all children (`children` array) and in 2nd phase I will find the age of all children in collection `age` using the `children` array.

Expected output:

```
[
 { name: "Joy", age:10},
 {name: "Joe", age:12},
 {name: "James", age:14},
]
```

How can I do this,without $lookup?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Both collections are sharded?`$lookup` can be executed on the sharded collection, but "from" cannot be sharded collection [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#sharded-collection-restrictions)

Comment: Yes, both collections are sharded.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the aggregation pipeline like this

```
db.man.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "Jack"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$children"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "age",
      foreignField: "name",
      localField: "children",
      as: "age"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$age"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$children",
      age: "$age.age"
    }
  }
])
```

Check the working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XLDtzAFlGNo)

Comment: Hum, I am upvoting it, It works. Is there any way doing this without $lookup ?

Comment: if you don't want to use either `$lookup or 2 queries`, then what you can do is, store name of the parent directly in you age collection as we know that name of parent is not going  to change that often, so we can store that redundant data to make the query faster

Comment: or you can store _id of the parent in age table too, that way you don't have to update the age table if the name of parent changes @MHJ

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the data from the `ages` collection and you can "join" another collection directly with an array:

```
db.man.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { name: "Jack" }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "age",
            localField: "children",
            foreignField: "name",
            as: "children"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$children"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: "$children.name",
            age: "$children.age",
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c7pCMKGPlru)

Comment: Hum, I am upvoting it, It works. Is there any way doing this without $lookup ?

Comment: @MHJ no, lookup is the only way to run your query across multiple collections, otherwise you need multiple queries

Comment: Just for information, do lookup works in sharded collection ?

Comment: @MHJ no, unsharded only and has to be the same database